# Pulse effect not working inside bootstrap Modal

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My pulse effect is not working inside the bootstrap modal. However, its working fine outside of it.

Perfectly working on normal page. Not working inside the bootstrap modal. I don't know why the modal is blocking this effect. What should I do?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Heart Beat
  var timeoutThrottle, back = true;
  $('#seventyfive').on('transitionend', function(e) {
    clearTimeout(timeoutThrottle);
    timeoutThrottle = setTimeout(function() {
      back = !back;
      pulse(back);
    }, 0);
  });
  var pulse = (function pulse(back) {
    $('#seventyfive').toggleClass('heartBeat', back);
    return pulse;
  })(back);
});
```

```css
.heart {
  color: #eb5e28;
  -webkit-animation: heathing 1s ease infinite;
  animation: heathing 1s ease infinite;
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: auto;
  height: 15px !important;
}

#seventyfive {
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: bold;
  /* margin-left: -22px; */
  /* margin-top: 3px; */
  font-size: 15px;
  opacity: 1;
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -o-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
}

#seventyfive.heartBeat {
  font-size: 16px;
  opacity: .5;
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -o-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
  transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-6khuMg9gaYr5AxOqhkVIODVIvm9ynTT5J4V1cfthmT+emCG6yVmEZsRHdxlotUnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">Launch demo modal</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body new-match">
        <div class="title">Hi Love <i class="fa fa-heart heart" id="seventyfive"></i></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you need to call this function on bootstrap's shown modal event

Comment: @user3337667 how?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use Bootstrap [modal events](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#events): `shown.bs.modal` and `hidden.bs.modal`.

```
$('#exampleModalCenter').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
  $('#seventyfive').addClass('heartBeat');
})
$('#exampleModalCenter').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  $('#seventyfive').removeClass('heartBeat');
})
```

The `heartBeat` class will be added when the modal is shown, and removed when hidden.